# Is there an HTTP PUT Method available for an ActionCard?

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm interested in updating a ServiceNow record via an ActionCard.  Updates to records in ServiceNow only accept a PUT.  Is there an action type of `HttpPUT` in lieu of `HttpPOST`?  A POST is simply denied with

`The remote endpoint returned an error (HTTP MethodNotAllowed). Please try again later.`

Since I'm using Microsoft Teams, I must use the message card format, per their docs:

"`However, if you are sending actionable messages via an Office 365 connector, or to a Microsoft Teams connector, you must continue to use the message card format`"

```
110       - "@type": ActionCard
111         name: Set Assignment Group
112         inputs:
113         - "@type": MultichoiceInput
114           id: list
115           title: Chose an assignment group
116           isMultiSelect: false
117           choices:
118             - display: IT Service Desk
119               value: 4546b6fg1r864z10wk42964pnh4bccpq
120         actions:
121         - "@type": HttpPOST
122           name: Save
123           target: https://servicenow_instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident/sys_id
124           headers:
125             - name: Authorization
126               value: Basic base64_encoded
127               body: "{'assignment_group': '{{list.value}}'}"
```

Comment: Action Card does not support HttpPut Method Please take a look at [Actions in action card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#actioncard-action)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm relatively new to these concepts here.  Based on the link provided, and my objective of posting a payload to a MS Connector I created (Incoming Webhook), and posting to the supplied URL https://outlook.office.com/webhook/blah.  In this case, it would seem that only the message card format is supported, as quoted from the docs "However, if you are sending actionable messages via an Office 365 connector, or to a Microsoft Teams connector, you must continue to use the message card format.".  Short of creating my own bot, do I have no options available here?

Comment: Yes, Connectors supports only Message Card as of now, If you still want to send adaptive card without setting up your own Bot as you mentioned, You can go with the [Microsoft Flow to send Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-adaptive-cards-teams)

Comment: Thank you for the links and the suggestions!  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updating answer based on new info]
Because this is just a backend call, with no UI, there's no way for the user to know if the call was successful, or even if it was made at all (i.e. they might push again to see). As a result, it really would be better if you handled the PUT internally somewhere. If you want a complex input/output, you could look at a Tab or Task window, but practically speaking, the best is probably just to have the button click go straight back to the Bot as an input, have the Bot make the call, and respond appropriately to the user.

What that means practically is having your card action change from an "Action.Http" to an [Action.Submit](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html). You'd want to have the Submit send a payload of some sort (like a "sys_id" or whatever you need for ServiceNow) on the button click, as the example shows (it's just sending "x" in the link). That way, you get the button click "invoke" so to speak, and the info you need to proceed, without need to maintain state specifically in your Bot.

The call will come through as a normal Turn to your Bot (like a normal message), but instead of having a "text" payload on the Activity, it will have a Value with a CommandId (basically an ID to identify the specific button) and whatever you send as the "data".

Your Bot can simply detect that this property is populated, call ServiceNow, and provide the user with an appropriate response like "ServiceNow Ticket Updated" or whatever.

Hope that helps

[Update] In the end this wasn't a Bot interaction at all - see the comments below for more info and solution

Comment: It's a back-end API call.  A json result is returned alongside an HTTP status 200, and it would far more convenient if other HTTP methods were available action types.  Otherwise, I like the idea of a proxy, outside of having to build another  component.  If this is something that can be done in Flow, then perhaps it won't be so bad. All in all, a user may belong to multiple groups, so I wanted a multiple choice drop down for them to select their relevant group, click a Save button which makes an HTTP PUT to ServiceNow to assign the assignment group the user selected in the teams card.

Comment: By the way, I've just re-looked at your original question and I see properly now that you're using ActionCards. Have you looked into the newer version of these, [Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#types-of-cards)? The concept is the same but there are of course a few differences. Adaptive Cards offer a lot more though, as far as I know

Comment: Thanks for the help Hilton!  I'm relatively new to these concepts here, and as I commented to @Trinetra-MSFT above, I'm using an Incoming Webhook connector, to which only the message card format is supported, as documented --> "However, if you are sending actionable messages via an Office 365 connector, or to a Microsoft Teams connector, you must continue to use the message card format."  I'm trying to find my way through the best approach here, and attempting to understand what I can do with out of the box features without having to develop my own bot (I'm not an MS developer) :)

Comment: So I can see that Adaptive Cards are not supported via connectors, which is what I am using.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card  Any tutorials on how to create a proxy via PowerApps or otherwise that can receive the POST and process it as you suggest?

Comment: okay - I think I found what you were talking about in creating a Flow.  Via an Instant Flow and setting up a "When an HTTP request is received".  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: oh, I didn't realise this was coming via a webhook, for some reason I thought a bot was sending the card, my bad! In this case, Flow could work, but you'll still have the issue of no response UI to the user - I'd suggest maybe going the earlier suggestion - just have the POST Url be to a web page (written in any lang) you host somewhere, that makes the actual call. Use the servicenow id you get, make the call, give the user a valid response, and some kind of message indicating they can close the window when done, something like that - that should be a reasonably simple + elegant solution.

Comment: Sounds good.  My bad for having not mentioned that.  I came to realize this after making more sense of the documentation :)  I really appreciate the suggestions!!

Comment: Glad to help and hope you come right - if not, just post again and we can pick it up further.

Comment: I was able to make some progress. I created a new Instant Flow from blank, and chose the trigger 'When an HTTP request is received'. I set a valid request body json schema, then added a step 'HTTP', and set the Method to PUT and a crafted URI from dynamic content (from the schema), as well as the body.  Advanced options were set to set up basic auth to the servicenow endpoint. This works perfectly from curl and postman, but from teams I get this: "The remote endpoint returned an error (HTTP Unauthorized). Please try again later."

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm able to hit the HTTP POST URL generated by the "HTTP request" step from Postman, and other places on the Internet (my company network, etc), but when I put that URL as the target to the HttpPOST type as an action, I'm getting the 401.  The issue I'm having is exactly as outlined here -> https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Issues-with-HTTPpost-inside-Message-Card/td-p/256581

Comment: So I figured it out after a couple of hours of searching and searching.  In short (and firstly), I needed to set the Authorization header.  Secondly, the Authorization header needs to be set to null.  Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements#action-authorization-header

Comment: ahh, that makes sense - was thinking about this and thinking that it's sending something, but not something that Flow can accept, hence the problem. Nice find and glad it's sorted!